# Android:Sqlite Fatal Exception Main

Tags: android

```
//hi i am trying to retrieve the data from database and display in my activity.but it is giving error fatal exception main.here when i click showall button all student details shouls get dispalyed.


public class four extends Activity {
    Button showall;
    MyDataBase mydb;
    ListView lv;
    int str;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.snd);

         mydb=new MyDataBase(four.this);
            mydb.openDB();




    showall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("INFO","ALL DETAILS");
            ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> p2 = mydb.getAllSDetails();

                lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    //coloum.xml contains four text view,and string contains my coloum names.

               SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(four.this, p2, R.layout.column,
                       new String[] {"_Sid","FName", "LName","clss","sec"}, new int[] {R.id.txtfname, R.id.txtlname,R.id.txtage,R.id.txtqual});
               lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);



                lv.setOnItemClickListener(select);

            }
        });
    }

            public OnItemClickListener select=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                        long arg3) {
                    int idd[] = mydb.gettingId();
                    str = idd[position];


                }

              };
}
```

// my error log .i am unable to solve the problem.is there any thing wrong i did in my program. my error log .i am unable to solve the problem.is there any thing wrong i did in my program.    can any one please guide me why i am getting the following error.

```
2-27 08:26:12.098: I/INFO(381): ALL DETAILS
12-27 08:26:12.098: I/INFO(381): database creation
12-27 08:26:12.108: I/INFO(381): Opening database
12-27 08:26:12.148: I/INFO(381): ALL DETAILS
12-27 08:26:12.158: D/AndroidRuntime(381): Shutting down VM
12-27 08:26:12.158: W/dalvikvm(381): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.four}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.four.onCreate(four.java:40)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: what code is on line 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not initialized your button "**showall**".

Something like

```
showall=(Button)findviewbyid(R.id.yourbuttonid);
```

are you missing this?

Comment: hey thank u so much.it was this error only.and i have also made one more error i have written R.layout.snd it should be r.layout.thrd.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be OOT here. When you get error running android, you'll always receive stacktrace. From there, you can decide to look at particular line of code that give error. For example, on your case:

```
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android/com.android.four}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This error tell you (by looking at the end of it's line) that an object is null when you try to use it.

Now, you might think: "hmm... what line is generating error?". Luckily, the it tell you that, by looking way down the stacktrace:

```
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 08:26:12.180: E/AndroidRuntime(381):  at com.android.four.onCreate(four.java:40)
```

See, when you get error, look for the message. If you don't understand the meaning of it, google the exact error. In your case `java.lang.NullPointerException`. After that, back again to stacktrace, to see what line actually generate this error by looking for `Caused by: {the error message}`. Just right after that line, you will see the actual line that produce error message. Go back to your code and check what code is in that line and why it generate such error message. In your case, it is `com.android.four.onCreate(four.java:40)`. Which means:

> Somewhere on `line 40` at `method onCreate()` from `class four` that reside at `file four.java` generate the error.

At this point, if you still don't know why that particular line generate error, you may ask here or somewhere else, by adding what information you already got (the error line, the error message, what you already do to check why it is error). By supplying these message, I believe you will get better answer, since people will see that you already has done some effort to find the problem.

Comment: hey thanks for all the explination.it was very usefull.and ya i have made one error in oncreate().i wrote R.layout.snd it should be R.layout.thrd.

Comment: @SnehaKoneru don't forget to pick one answer you seem fit your situation

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

there is your error hiding

what to do ?

1.line 40 find it.

2.check  for declarations at this point (you might have just missed out on initializing)

3.Run your code error free

Is this line40

```
public OnItemClickListener select=new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

Also could I suggest you use Cursor to retrieve your values from a database. Declare the cursor in the main class(also initialize) and then use it to get your values.

Comment: thank u Vinoth.i wll try to use Cursor .and ya there was a error in line 40.i have to write showall=(Button)findviewbyid(R.id.button1);i didnt declare.